# Cell formatting issue

Tags: excel, formatting

I have exported thousands of ratios (e.g. 63:01) but Excel is reading it as a time (e.g. 1/2/1900  3:01:00 PM). The ratios range from 1:01 to beyond 63:01... I need the ratio NOT to show as a date. Is there a way to do that? I've tried copying/pasting in different ways into columns formatted in different ways but can't seem to get it right.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set the format of the cells as `text` before entering your data. Then it shouldn't automatically set it to a `date`. Just make sure to set all the cells that need to be a ratio as `text` first. So if it's an entire column then select the column and then change format to `text` and then paste the data.